# Cursor and text appearing just to the left of EditText box

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create a EditText box but I am running into the following issue when the EditText is selected:

[image] [image]

As you can see the cursor and text appears to the left of the box. I am not sure what I am doing that could cause that problem, and would like to see if anyone here knows a solution. Here is some relevant code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@drawable/ExpandableDivider"
            android:showDividers="middle">
            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/last_name_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Last Name*"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/searchLastNameEditText"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:background="@drawable/componentbackground" />
        </LinearLayout>
        ...
```

Things appear fine in the designer. Here is some more:

```
lastNameLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.last_name_layout);
lastName = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.searchLastNameEditText);
lastName.Background = UIComponents.ComponentUtils.getDrawable(this, Resource.Drawable.componentbackground);
lastName.SetPadding(0, dp(10), 0, dp(10));
```

I have tested this on a Nexus 5 emulator and a physical HTC M8 and get the same results.

**EDIT: Include `component background`:**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- dropshadow -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC"/>
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC"/>
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#40CCCCCC"/>
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC"/>
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#60CCCCCC"/>
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<!--background-->
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#eeeeee"/>
        <stroke android:color="#AAAAAA" android:width="1dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably related to:  `android:background="@drawable/componentbackground"`.  Because if that graphic is offset to the right, like it appears to be, it will appear that the text is floating too far left.

The text appears perfectly lined up with the text above it.  It's the graphic that's off.

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out! I have edited my question to include the `@drawable/componentbackground` if you wouldn't mind taking a look at that

Comment: I think you should try dropping the radius, just to see if that helps.  It may be creating a sort-of false margin.

Comment: Have you tried setting the internal padding?  Right now it's 1dp.